# Why do I get java.lang.IllegalStateException: Scanner closed

Tags: java

Silly question but I've been receiving this error message and i don't understand the error message. Any help in helping me understand my short comings would be much appreciated

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class Exercise9 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter x coordinate for point 1: ");   
    double x1 = input.nextDouble();
    input.close();

    System.out.print("Enter y coordinate for point : ");    
    double y1 = input.nextDouble();
    input.close();

    System.out.print("Enter x coordinate for point 2: ");   
    double x2 = input.nextDouble();
    input.close();

    System.out.print("Enter y coordinate for point 2: ");   
    double y2 = input.nextDouble();
    input.close();
        
    double distance = Math.sqrt((x2-x1)*(x2-x1)+(y2-y1)*(y2-y1));
    System.out.println("The distance between the two points is" +distance); 
     }
     }
```

https://pastebin.pl/view/8af98c21

```
Enter y coordinate for point : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Scanner closed
at java.base/java.util.Scanner.ensureOpen(Scanner.java:1150)
at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1573)
at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2564)
at Exercise9.main(Exercise9.java:12)
```

Comment: You can only call `input.close();` once and it will not allow you to use `input` afterwards.

Comment: Just don't close the Scanner object. It will do that when the application ends.

Comment: **Also**, calling `input.close()` will close any associated resources; in this case `System.in`

Comment: Without intending to be rude, I'm wondering why you wrote those repeated 'close' calls and what you thought they would do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after you call `input.close();` then the Scanner Object will be closed. no need to repeat, just once you call `input.close();`